# Integration - A vehicle is moving with a velocity described by...

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm not sure how I should do this question and I have no real idea on how I should approach it successfully. Here's the question:

A vehicle is moving with a velocity described by $v=4t^3+10$.

Where $v$ is in $ms^{-1}$ and $t$ is in seconds.

Find the distance it travels in the interval $t = 0$ and $t = 3.$

That's the question which I have had a go at but I substituted the $0$ and $3$ in for the $t$ to find the velocities at those times but I have a feeling that that's the wrong approach since this is integration.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The distance is $$\int_{t=0}^3 (4t^3+10)\ dt=[t^4+10t]_0^3=81+30=111$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that velocity is the change in the position per time:
$$v(t)=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
Therefore,
$$x=\int_0^{x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}v(t)\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^3(4t^3+10)\mathrm{d}t$$
Can you go from here?

The same is true for higher derivatives. For example, if $a(t)$ is acceleration,
$$a(t)=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
and
$$v=\int_0^{v}\mathrm{d}v=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}a(t)\mathrm{d}t$$